# Adobe Javascript add ":" to 4 digit time and validate as time

Tags: javascript, time, adobe

I have a Adobe form with some Javascripting. I have a start time and end time and a total field. I would like the user to add a four digit(24hr) start/end time and the field to add the ":" Automatically into the time, the field then needs to been "seen" as a time, as I have a script that runs in the total field that shows the total hours and minutes.

I have tried many variations with no success, the code I have to calculate the two fields is

```
var cStart = this.getField("Start_1").value;
var cStop = this.getField("Finish_1").value;

if (cStart != "" && cStop != "") {
    var tStart = parseTime(cStart);
    var tStop = parseTime(cStop);
    var total = (tStop - tStart) / (1000*60*60);

    event.value = (total < 0 ? total += 24 : total);
} else {
    event.value = "";
}
```

Any help to sorth this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what are the values of `cStart` and `cStop`? Are they values of 4 integers?

Comment: No sorry, they should be Start_1 and Finish_1

Comment: I have two fields, Start_1 (start work hours) and Finish_1 (end of work hours) I would like the user to add just 4 digits to these two fields. In the third field I have the above script to total the amount of hours worked, and display in a time format e.g. 3.45 instead of 3.75 3 and 3/4 hours. I am not great with scripting I can at times change things to suit some needs, but I can’t write it. Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: You mention in the question title that you want the colon (`:`) in the result but in the comment you display a period (`.`)

Comment: Hi wmash, thank you very much for your help, I think maybe I havn't explained myself correctly. I have created a sample document with what I am after, if your able to take a look at it, I would really appreciate it. You can download it from my dropbox.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzbebbcen3kf8x1/parseTime.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Please see my amended JS Fiddle. The code will need splitting up but it will give you what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood you correctly when you mentioned the formatting. The easiest and least disruptive way I though of doing this from what you already had was to parse the times to JS `Date`. Subtract these times from each other. Convert the result to a string and concatenate in a `:`.

> the field then needs to been "seen" as a time

I was confused as to what you meant by the statement above but assumed you did not care of the date type and that it only **views** as a time.

```
var cStart = this.getField("Start_1").value;
var cStop = this.getField("Finish_1").value;

if (cStart != "" && cStop != "") {
    var tStart = new Date().setTime(cStart);
    var tStop = new Date().setTime(cStop);
    var total = (tStop - tStart).toString();

    var minutes = total.substr(total.length - 2, total.length);
    var hours = total.substr(0, total.length - 2);

    event.value = hours + ":" + minutes;
} else {
    event.value = "";
}
```

Here is a basic [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6ykv368/135/)